# How to use a volumebuttonhandler to take a picture in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, uikit, uiimagepickercontroller

When you take a picture using the `UIViewControllerRepresentable` the user has to confirm the image taken by pressing "Use Photo" or "Retake" photo. I've been trying to get rid of this feature by using a third party library called `JPSVolumeButtonHandler` to detect volume button presses and calling `takePicture()` whenever the user presses one of the volume buttons, because apparently when `takePicture()` is called directly there is no confirmation option, and I don't want to use any gui buttons to take a picture. I think the normal event handler for this interferes with the JPS library and my solution to this was opening the imagepicker when the user presses one of the volume buttons and then calling `takePicture()` automatically after a few seconds.
*I might have to try and use AVFoundation if nothing else works*

**How can we call the takePicture() method from the ContentView struct when the user presses the volume buttons?**

I know we can do something like this to make the program take a picture automatically when we start the program. Calling `startCaptureTimer` from makeUIViewController

```
class Coordinator: NSObject, UINavigationControllerDelegate, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate {
        var parent: ImagePicker
        private var timer: Timer? // add Timer

        init(parent: ImagePicker) {
            self.parent = parent
        }
        
        // add this function to start the Timer which calls takePicture
    -->   func startCaptureTimer(for picker: UIImagePickerController) {
            timer?.invalidate()
            
            timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 4, repeats: false, block: { timer in
                picker.takePicture()
            })
        }

    //Coordinator continued...
} 

func makeUIViewController(context: Context) -> UIImagePickerController {
        let picker = UIImagePickerController()
        picker.delegate = context.coordinator
        picker.sourceType = .camera
        picker.allowsEditing = false
        picker.showsCameraControls = false // hide default controls
   -->  context.coordinator.startCaptureTimer(for: picker) // start capture timer

        return picker
    }
```

But how can we call the method from ContentView so that when the library detects a volume button press, it takes a picture?

```
import SwiftUI
import UIKit
import JPSVolumeButtonHandler

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var isImagePickerPresented = false
    @State private var capturedImage: UIImage?
    @State private var isCameraAuthorized = false
    @State private var volumeHandler: JPSVolumeButtonHandler?
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            
            Button("Take Photo") {
                isImagePickerPresented.toggle()
                
            }
            .sheet(isPresented: $isImagePickerPresented, onDismiss: {
                
            }) {
                ImagePicker(image: $capturedImage, onImageCapture: { imageData in
                    if let imageData = imageData {
                        uploadImage(imageData: imageData)
                    }
                })
            }
            .onAppear {
                volumeHandler = JPSVolumeButtonHandler(up: {
                    
                }, downBlock: {
    --->                
                })
                        
                volumeHandler?.start(true)
                
                
                isImagePickerPresented.toggle()
            }
            
            Button(action: {
                if let imageData = capturedImage?.jpegData(compressionQuality: 0.5) {
                    uploadImage(imageData: imageData)
                }
            }) {
                VStack {
                    Text("Cool")
                        .font(.system(size: 70))
                        .padding(69)
                        .overlay(
                            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 15)
                                .stroke(Color.black, lineWidth: 8)
                        )
                }
                .contentShape(Rectangle())
            }
            .background(Color.red)
            .foregroundColor(.white)
            .cornerRadius(15)
        }
        .background(
            Image("gigachad")
                .scaledToFit()
                .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
        )
    }
    
}
@main
struct BacknForth: App {
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
        }
    }
}
```

Here's the rest/entire imagepicker code

```
import SwiftUI
import UIKit
import JPSVolumeButtonHandler

struct ImagePicker: UIViewControllerRepresentable {
    @Binding var image: UIImage?
    var onImageCapture: ((Data?) -> Void)
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode

    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        return Coordinator(parent: self)
    }

    func makeUIViewController(context: Context) -> UIImagePickerController {
        let picker = UIImagePickerController()
        picker.delegate = context.coordinator
        picker.sourceType = .camera
        picker.allowsEditing = false
        picker.showCameraControls = false
        
        return picker
    }
    
    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: UIImagePickerController, context: Context) {}

    class Coordinator: NSObject, UINavigationControllerDelegate, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate {
        var parent: ImagePicker

        init(parent: ImagePicker) {
            self.parent = parent
        }

        func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey: Any]) {
            if let uiImage = info[.originalImage] as? UIImage {
                parent.image = uiImage

                
                let imageData = uiImage.jpegData(compressionQuality: 0.5)
                parent.onImageCapture(imageData)
            }

            parent.presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()  // Dismiss the ImagePicker
        }
    }
}
```

Creating an object in .onAppear out of UIImagePickerController and then trying to access takePicture() doesn't work because nothing happens when you run it. I'm assuming because it's not the same instance. I've heard that you can create like a custom view and then make your own ui elements that calls takePicture(), but I only want to use the volume buttons and I don't know if that solves it. Also perhaps @Binding could be used for this but I'm unsure.